# How can I dynamically generate a multicolored circle with only 1 div in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can make a set of circles that are all the appropriate color using multiple div elements and the css file for the page.  My current task however is to only use a single div element to dynamically create a target in javascript and not css that has multiple colored rings, modeled after [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UJ7I.png) image.  I started something like this:

```
var containerDiv = document.getElementById("container");
containerDiv.style.width = "200px";
containerDiv.style.height = "200px";
```

But this would only set the biggest circle that I need if anything.  I am not sure how to create the smaller, different colored circles inside the target dynamically.

Comment: have you tried inset shadow or radial-gradient ? and where did you fail ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I failed in that I know how to do it in css, but I cannot seem to be able to do it in javascript. I started by creating what would be the largest circle, but I am not sure how to create smaller colored circles from the one large one without creating new div elements.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55826619/8620333

Answer (score 2):

the easiest is inset shadow:

```css
#container {
  height:200px;width:200px;
  border-radius:50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px gray ,
    inset 0 0 0 10px white,
    inset 0 0 0 20px black,
    inset 0 0 0 35px white,
    inset 0 0 0 50px black,
    inset 0 0 0 65px rgb(64, 171, 191),
    inset 0 0 0 85px rgb(253, 23, 0),
    inset  0 0 0 100px rgb(255, 255, 51);
}

/* demo purpose */
html {display:flex;min-height:100vh;}
body {margin:auto;}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```